# Why does isAnnotationPresent work differently between Java 7 and Java 8?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-8, java-7

I just discovered this today when one of my unit tests failed because of upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8. The unit test calls a method which tries to find an annotation on a method which is annotated on a child class but with a different return type.

In Java 7, `isAnnotationPresent` seems to only find annotations if they were really declared in code. In Java 8, `isAnnotationPresent` seems to include annotations that were declared in child classes.

To illustrate this I created a simple (??) test class IAPTest (for IsAnnotationPresentTest).

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class IAPTest {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface Anno {
    }
    public static interface I {
    }
    public static interface IE extends I {
    }
    public static class A {
        protected I method() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static class B extends A {
        @Anno
        protected IE method() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method method : B.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().equals("method") && I.class.equals(method.getReturnType())) {
                System.out.println(method.isAnnotationPresent(Anno.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the latest Java 7 (1.7.0_79 at time of writing), this method prints "false". On the latest Java 8 (1.8.0_66 at time of writing), this method prints "true". I would intuitively expect it to print "false".

Why is this? Does this indicate a bug in Java or an intended change in how Java works?

**EDIT**: Just to show the exact commands I used to replicate this (in a directory with IAPTest.java identical to the code block above):

```
C:\test-isannotationpresent>del *.class

C:\test-isannotationpresent>set JAVA_HOME=C:\nma\Toolsets\AJB1\OracleJDK\jdk1.8.0_66

C:\test-isannotationpresent>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\nma\Toolsets\AJB1\OracleJDK\jdk1.8.0_66\bin

C:\test-isannotationpresent>java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

C:\test-isannotationpresent>javac IAPTest.java

C:\test-isannotationpresent>java IAPTest
true

C:\test-isannotationpresent>
```

Comment: Hmm, this prints `false` for me: Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, JDK 1.8.0_51.

Comment: Why do you think that annotations “were declared in child classes”? You have annotated the method in `B` and you are searching the *declared methods* of `B` and nothing else. There are no child classes involved.

Comment: @Holger when I search for the declared methods of `B` I find two methods. One method represents the method on the child class and one represents the method on the parent class. You can tell this from the return types. `B.class.getDeclaredMethods().length == 2` on both Java 7 and 8. Because I am checking the return type to ensure that the parent class method is the one being referred to (return type is `I` rather than `IE`), the method in `A` does not have the annotation, but only has the annotation in the child class `B`.

Comment: @Tunaki I just tested with your JDK version (build 1.8.0_51-b16) and I got "true". I'm running Java directly (not through Eclipse)

Comment: @Holger I did not say that `B` has child classes (subclasses). `A` has subclasses. The method returned is a synthetic method from the parent class. I also never said I don't believe you that the method I'm looking at was not declared within `B`. I agree with you. I don't know why you seem angry towards me but anyway my question has been answered now.

Comment: @Holger I do agree with you. If you invoke `getDeclaredMethods()` on `B` you get the declared methods of `B` and nothing else. I don't see any need to continue this discussion.

Comment: So why did you write the opposite multiple times?

Comment: @Holger I used terms like "represents" and "from" to describe bridge methods, but I never said that I got declared methods from another class. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I bear no ill will towards you. I notice you have now deleted your earlier comments.

Comment: In your question you are saying “*In Java 8, `isAnnotationPresent` seems to include annotations that were declared in child classes*” which is a conclusion that contradicts the fact that the annotation is present in `B` and you are only examining methods of `B`. Finding the annotation present in a class when you examine exactly that class isn’t surprising. And since you said in one comment “*Because I am checking the return type to ensure that the parent class method is the one being referred to*”, you *did* think you were getting a parent class’ method in the result of `getDeclaredMethods`

Comment: @Holger Again, I apologise if my wording did not clearly express to you what I was trying to say. Beyond that, I don't think there is a need to continue this discussion. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is related to a change mentioned in the [java 8 compatibility guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)

> As of this release, parameter and method annotations are copied to
>   synthetic bridge methods.This fix implies that now for programs like:
>
> ```
> @Target(value = {ElementType.PARAMETER})
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @interface ParamAnnotation {}  
> @Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD})
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @interface MethodAnnotation {}  
> abstract class T<A,B> {
>     B m(A a){
>         return null;
>     }  
> }    
> class CovariantReturnType extends T<Integer, Integer> {
>     @MethodAnnotation
>     Integer m(@ParamAnnotation Integer i) {
>         return i;
>     }
>
>     public class VisibilityChange extends CovariantReturnType {}   
> }
> ```
>
> Each generated bridge method will have all the annotations of the
>   method it redirects to. Parameter annotations will also be copied.
>   This change in the behavior may impact some annotations processor or
>   in general any application that use the annotations.

The second method that returns an `I` instead of an `IE` is a synthetic method generated because you have a narrower return type in the overridden method than in the super class.  Note that it's not present in the list of declared methods if you don't have a narrowing return type.  So I think this is not a bug, but a deliberate change.

Comment: Great answer! Not only did you provide me with the reasoning, and documentation quote, but also the way to fix my unit test to work on Java 8 - I just need to use `isSynthetic`. Thanks!